# how to use spawn_urdf_model service

Tags: ros, gazebo, spawn

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone

Currently I am trying to spawn a robot by calling spawn_urdf_model service. But, now matter what I did with it, it always failed to call the service. I think the problem is that I do not know how to assign value to model_xml field of gazebo_msgs::spawnmodel srv.

Does anyone know how to use this service? Especially, could anyone offer me some examples about how to use this service.

Thank you very much

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259934/how-to-use-spawn_urdf_model-service/) by [jasonwang538@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/30092/jasonwang538@gmail.com/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2017-04-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `model_xml` field should contain the contents of a URDF file. It's a string, so read the contents of a URDF file into a string and assign it to the `model_xml` field.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2017-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0